# Need help writing this specific bash script

Tags: bash, shell

1. Construct the pipe to execute the following job.
   "Output of ls should be displayed on the screen and from this output the lines 
   containing the word ‘poem’ should be counted and the count should be 
   stored in a file.”

Comment: smells like homework. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: It's not homework, I have a final and this was a question on our study guide. I got everything else right except for this. This is what I have so far ls | grep poem | wc -w > file     I'm stuck because I can't print out the contents using ls

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt was close:

```
ls | tee /dev/tty | grep poem | wc -l >number_of_poems
```

The `tee /dev/tty` copies all `ls` output to the terminal.  This satisfies the requirement that "Output of ls should be displayed on the screen." while also sending `ls`'s output to `grep`'s stdin.

This can be further simplified:

```
ls | tee /dev/tty | grep -c poem >number_of_poems
```

Note that neither of these solutions require `bash`.  Both will work with lesser shells and, in particular, with `dash` which is the default `/bin/sh` under debian-like systems.

Answer (score 1):

If bash is allowed, use a process substitution as the receiver for tee

```
ls | tee >( grep -c poem > number.of.poetry.files)
```

Comment: +10 if i could! Simply - this is **THE** solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework assignment :)

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
ls -l | grep -c poem >> file.txt
```

The first ls will display the output on the screen
The next line uses a series of pipes to output the number of files/directories containing "poem"

If there were 5 files with poem in them, file.txt would read 5. If file.txt already exists, the new count will be appended to the end. If you want overwrite file each time, change the line to read `ls -l | grep -c poem > file.txt`